# Запись из текстового компонента в файл

Tags: java

Как сделать сто бы при нажатии на кнопку из компонента "jTextField1" происходила запись в файл "Famili"?

```
  try {
    File file = new File("Famili.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
                }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

    out.writeObject(jTextField1);

    } catch (Exception e) {}
      e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мои экстрасенсорные способности меня не подводят и jTextField1 - это объект класса java.awt.TextField, то достаточно сделать так:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileOut.write(jTextField1.getText().getBytes());
fileOut.close();
```

Не забудьте вызвать close(). Для надежности, можно вызвать его в блоке finally.

Comment: А если в файле есть запись которая нужна, как можно сделать что бы дописать данные ?

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);